# Showing homogeneity of a quotient Riemannian manifold quotiented by a discrete subgroup .

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, group-actions, quotient-spaces

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $(M,g)$ be a homogeneous  Riemannian manifold and $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of Isom$(M,g):=G.$ Let, the normaliser of $\Gamma = N_G(\Gamma):=N$ acts transitively on $M.$ Then show $(\bar{M}:=M/{\Gamma},\bar{g})$ is also a homogeneous space.

Give an example of $(M,g)$ where $N$ acts transitively on $M.$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ I can't find where to exactly use the fact that $N$ acts transitively on $M.$

Since, the quotient map $q:M\to M/{\Gamma}$ is a local isometry  (because $\Gamma$ acts freely and properly discontinuously on $M$) and $M$ is homogeneous then it turns out $M/{\Gamma}$ is also homogeneous.

I can't find where I am doing wrong ?

A hint for both the problem and the example is very much needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you consider $S^3$ as a homogeneous space under that action by $SO(4)$, you can come up with examples of finite quotients which are homogeneous or inhomogeneous simply by varying the finite subgroup a bit.

Comment: Sorry I edited . I have to give an example . Apart from the example, how to solve that problem to show $M/{\Gamma}$ is homogeneous.?

Comment: Show that $N$ acts transitively on $\overline{M}$ (but the isotropy group can be larger than $\Gamma$)